# How to wipe cache from Mi Recovery Mode (no root, no OEM unlocked)?

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, cache

I saturated my phone memory, and while attempting to restart it to delete files, it got stuck on the "Mi" logo. I only have a partial backup.

Phone: Xiaomi Redmi Note 5, not rooted, not "OEM" unlocked.

What I want to do: **wipe the cache** (in the hopes that it will solve the problem), or if possible save the data to do a factory reset.

What I can do: I can access the Mi 3.0 recovery mode, use adb and fastboot.

What I can't do: The recovery mode doesn't offer a "wipe cache" option (only factory reset), and I can't wipe cache through adb or fastboot because the phone is not unlocked, a few examples :

```
adb shell su -c "rm -rf /data/data/<app's package>/cache/*"
error: closed

fastboot erase cache
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this ext4 partition?
Erasing 'cache'                                    FAILED (remote: 'Erase is not allowed in Lock State')
fastboot: error: Command failed

fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
Sending 'recovery' (35280 KB)                      OKAY [  0.856s]
Writing 'recovery'                                 FAILED (remote: 'Flashing is not allowed in Lock State')
```

Recovery mode also has a "pcsuite.mi.com" option, but I can't seem to make it work. I don't know how to use it, even if I have installed the Mi Suite, it doesn't detect my phone.

Do you think there is a possibility here to wipe the cache ? Or is it impossible and I must do a factory reset ?

Comment: @alecxs A little update: after a few manipulations (new loader because preexisting ones didn't work on Redmi Note 5, patching the driver, desactivating some windows securities) we solved a USB error 5, but still get a Sahara Error. I think I'm going to stop here, I was glad I could try this far. I am going to do a reset to factory setting. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137620/discussion-on-question-by-agathe-how-to-wipe-cache-from-mi-recovery-mode-no-roo).